# Laravel Themes is really using Vue Js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am confused about something:
Does this themes really use Vue JS ? https://material-dashboard-laravel.creative-tim.com/docs/getting-started/file-structure.html
I don't see any .vue file in the structure of the file tree. 
On the top of this the Vue Devtools of Chrome doesn't see those page as Vue page.
How come ?
I have setup the laravel vue material dashboard on my localhost following this process: https://material-dashboard-laravel.creative-tim.com/docs/getting-started/laravel-setup.html  but still the VueDevtools doesn't detect Vue and I find the loading of the page quite slow...
Your opinion ?

Comment: It doesn't claim it uses Vue. Seems like it doesn't. Plain jQuery.

Comment: it asked to install Vue package, looke it here : https://material-dashboard-laravel.creative-tim.com/docs/getting-started/laravel-setup.html

Comment: Seems like pasted instruction. Nothing else suggests that Vue is in use.

Comment: No, i is just bootstral + jquery.